# SQL запрос к нескольким таблицам с функцией COUNT()

Tags: php, sql

Есть 3 таблицы в БД. Во всех 3-х таблицах есть одинаковое поле "booster". Смысл в том, что мне надо подсчитать ОДНИМ запросом кол-во полей "booster" при помощи COUNT(), во всех 3-х таблицах через оператор WHERE.

Сделать это 3-мя запросами ума много не надо, но сделать одним у меня не хватает знаний SQL. У меня получилось сделать это без COUNT(), но без неё нет смысла.

Прилагаю пример моего рабочего быдлокода:

```
include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/engine/includes/db.inc.php';

        session_start();

        //BEGIN БЫДЛОКОД!!!

        try 
        {
            $sql = 'SELECT COUNT(booster) FROM boost_orders WHERE booster = :booster';
            $s = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $s->bindValue(':booster', $_SESSION['login']);
            $s->execute();
        } 
        catch (PDOException $e) 
        {
            $error = 'Forbidden 353!!!';
            include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/engine/includes/errors.inc.php';
            exit();
        }

        $row_1 = $s->fetchColumn();

        try 
        {
            $sql = 'SELECT COUNT(booster) FROM сalibr_orders WHERE booster = :booster';
            $s = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $s->bindValue(':booster', $_SESSION['login']);
            $s->execute();
        } 
        catch (PDOException $e) 
        {
            $error = 'Forbidden 353!!!';
            include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/engine/includes/errors.inc.php';
            exit();
        }

        $row_2 = $s->fetchColumn();

        try 
        {
            $sql = 'SELECT COUNT(booster) FROM lp_orders WHERE booster = :booster';
            $s = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $s->bindValue(':booster', $_SESSION['login']);
            $s->execute();
        } 
        catch (PDOException $e) 
        {
            $error = 'Forbidden 353!!!';
            include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/engine/includes/errors.inc.php';
            exit();
        }

        $row_3 = $s->fetchColumn();

        $total = $row_1 + $row_2 + $row_3;

        if ($total >= 1)
        {
            $error = 'Вы не можете брать больше одного заказа!';
            include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/engine/includes/errors.inc.php';
            exit();
        }

        //END БЫДЛОКОД!!!
```

Comment: `if ($total >= 1)` - это могло бы всё упростить.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

нужно использовать оператор UNION ALL для того, чтобы склеить выборки по 3-м таблицам, и на склеенную таблицу уже применять COUNT:

```
select COUNT(*) from (SELECT booster from t1 where booster = :booster 
UNION ALL SELECT booster from t2 where booster = :booster 
UNION ALL SELECT booster from t3 where booster = :booster) as query
```

В любой нормальной базе с поддержкой ANSI SQL будет работать.

Comment: Да, всё отлично работает. Большое спасибо.